# Cant recognise a Damaged component of switched-mode power supply

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics

I was repairing an smps ATX power supply I found a damaged component that I could not it recognise. I thought it's a power switch since it was mounted to a heat sink along with tow D13007 NPN power transistors and I could not find the datasheet due to the missing part number after explosion .Can someone with expertise in this type of circuits guess what this could be?
EDIT :
[image]
[image]
EDIT : 
[image]
[image]

Comment: It looks like maybe you meant to upload 2 pictures, but instead uploaded the same one twice? As it stands I don't think you've provided enough info to answer the question. What power supply model is this? And what do the traces on the back leading away from it look like? A clear picture of the area around the part would be helpful too.

Comment: Thanks for the recification, I have a circuit diagram I will upload it